# Vue watching fields triggered only from UI

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My page contains a component with three fields, that represents a user selection:

- State (active, disabled)
- Location (A building, B building)
- Name (Test User)

These three fields are in connected to each other and all of the fields are list so if the user wants to select another user for example:

- first selecting an active state (selecting all the locations of the active users)
- then the selecting the A building (selecting all the users who works in A building)
- finally selects Test User.

In my solution in the component I have created 3 watch fields (selectedUserState, selectedLocation, selectedUserFullName), and if one of them is changed refreshes the other list of the fields:

```
var filter = Vue.component('UserFilter', {
template: '#userfilter-template',                        
data() {
    return {
        userFilter: {},
        selectedUserState: "",
        selectedLocation: "",
        selectedUserFullName: ""
    }
},
watch: {
    selectedUserState: function (newValue, oldValue) {
        var searchContext = {};

        searchContext.State = this.selectedUserState.Key;

        this.refreshFilter(searchContext);
    },
    selectedLocation: function (newValue, oldValue) {                
        var searchContext = {};

        searchContext.State = this.selectedUserState.Key;

        if (this.selectedLocation) {
            searchContext.LocationID = this.selectedLocation.Key;
        }

        this.refreshFilter(searchContext);               
    },
    selectedUserFullName: function (newValue, oldValue) {               
        var searchContext = {};

        searchContext.State = this.selectedUserState.Key;

        if (this.selectedLocation) {
            searchContext.LocationID = this.selectedLocation.Key;
        }

        if (this.selectedUserFullName) {
            searchContext.FullName = this.selectedUserFullName;
        }

        this.refreshFilter(searchContext);                
    }           
},
methods: {                     
    refreshFilter(searchContext) {
       postData(url, { searchContext: searchContext })
            .then(response => {
                if (response) {
                    this.userFilter = response.data.result;

                    if (this.selectedUserFullName !== this.userFilter.selectedUserFullName) {
                        this.selectedUserFullName = this.userFilter.selectedUserFullName;
                    }

                    if (this.selectedLocation !== this.userFilter.selectedLocation) {
                        this.selectedLocation = this.userFilter.selectedLocation;
                    }

                    if (this.selectedUserState !== this.userFilter.selectedUserState) {
                        this.selectedUserState = this.userFilter.selectedUserState;
                    }
                }
            });
    }           
},
mounted() {
    this.refreshFilter(null);
}});
```

The problem is that i am only wants to trigger these watch fields if the user change them in the UI, but it triggers in the refreshing method when setting the new value and it triggers unneccessary refreshes.

I tried to find a unwatch method that removes triggers and watch method that bind triggers without any success.

Thanks your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this would be to put a on change even on your UI (drop downs I guess?)

Which would trigger functions that basically do what your watch functions currently do.